# how to unset the foreground color of whitespace-mode for Emacs

Tags: emacs, whitespace, long-lines

In programming files, I use whitespace-mode to highlight the tab and long lines. The default highlighting is too garnish for me.I just want to highlight them with a gray background and keep whatever normal color it should be for the font. How could I set that?

The following setup does not work. I'd like the code beyond 80 columns appearing yellowish, as the characters inside 80 columns in the snapshot.

```
;; face for long lines' tails
(set-face-attribute 'whitespace-line nil
                    :background "#555"
                    :weight 'bold)

;; face for Tabs
(set-face-attribute 'whitespace-tab nil
                    :background "#555"
                    :weight 'bold)
```

[image: whitespace-mode]

Comment: Same problem.  In default theme, trailing whitespace is a nice grey.  In every other color theme, it blazes red as if some fatal error.  The set-face-attribute answer below has no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set-face-attribute` changes only the attributes you specify.

Set `:foreground` to `nil`:

```
(set-face-attribute 'whitespace-line nil
                    :foreground nil
                    :background "#555"
                    :weight 'bold)
```

Comment: I know, but nil will set the font white not yellow.

Comment: I see. Short answer: you can't do it. Longer answer: you'd need to patch whitespace.el: https://gist.github.com/72d39c507d56c5c5e0ed

Comment: I am looking for something similar to defadvice as for function

Comment: You could get this by advising both `whitespace-color-on` and `font-lock-add-keywords`, setting some var to to in the former, checking its value in the latter and forcibly setting the `override` value in the `keywords` spec to `prepend`, but really, it's a horrible solution.

Comment: Send a feature request to the Emacs bug tracker, I'm sure we can get this change into trunk in no time. Using `prepend` there makes sense.

Comment: with the command in this answer, i get an error::::  error: Invalid face, whitespace-line

Comment: @MadhavanKumar Try `(require 'whitespace)` first.

Answer (score 3):

For me the unpleasant color turned out to be trailing-whitespace and I'm using this:

```
;; whitepace looks rediculous in color themes.
(defadvice color-theme-install (after my-color-theme-install-after activate)
  "Fix trailing-whitespace after color theme destroys it"
  (set-face-attribute 'trailing-whitespace nil
                      :foreground 'unspecified
                      :inverse-video 'unspecified
                      :slant 'unspecified
                      :weight 'unspecified
                      :background "#fff"))
```

Comment: Doing this for both trailing-whitespace and whitespace-line worked for me with emacs 24.4 -- except that I used (add-hook 'python-mode-hook '(lambda () (set-face-attribute ...))).  No doubt that's not the best place, but worked for my purpose.